# Нужна ли запятая в этом случае: церковь Преображения Господня(,) что на Песках?

Tags: запятые

- церковь Преображения Господня(,) что на Песках
- церковь Святого Иоанна Предтечи(,) что на Знаменке

Меняется ли написание просто в названии (заглавии) или в середине предложения? Менялись ли правила постановки запятой в этом случае (есть варианты без и с запятой)?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь ставится запятая, так как сочетание ‟что на песках” является неполным определительным предложением, сокращенным от: ‟что находится на Песках”.
Меняется ли написание? В конце не ставится точка, но запятые в середине заглавия ставятся.

Comment: Точка ставится независимо от этого, только в случае, если это предложение.

Comment: Может и так. Просто обычно у заглавия нет точки в конце.

Comment: Да, у заглавия нет точки, конечно. :)